# How can i handle if i pass NULL to this function? freeing Linkedlist in C

Tags: c, linked-list, null, free

i have tried to handle the segmentation fault.
if there is a way to handle NULL passed to this function, help me out.

```
void freeList(struct Node **head_ref) 
    { 
    struct Node *tmp,*node;
    node=*head_ref;
    while (node != NULL) 
        { 
        tmp=node;
        node = node->next; 
        //printf("  ..Free %d \n", tmp->data);      
        free(tmp);
        } 
    *head_ref=NULL;
    }

int main (){
    /* do stuff */
    freeList(NULL);
    /* do stuff */
    }
```

Comment: Check whether or not it's `NULL` before `node=*head_ref;`, and exit the function early if it is.

Comment: thanks, worked out when i a check whether `head_ref ` is `NULL` or not without using *

Answer (score -2):

There is no need to check within the function whether the passed pointer (`struct Node **head_ref`) is equal to `NULL`. Just provide a description to the function that in this case the function has undefined behavior. For example write in a comment that "head_ref shall not be a null pointer and shall point to a valid pointer to the head node of a list".

Or you could insert assert macro like

```
#include <assert.h>

//...

void freeList(struct Node **head_ref) 
{
    assert( head_ref != NULL );
    //...
```

It is the responsibility of the user of the function to pass a pointer to the pointer to the head node not equal to `NULL`. The function should only check whether the passed by reference list is empty or not.

Moreover without such a check it will help users of the function to find their bugs.

Making such a check you in fact are hiding from the user of your function a bug in his program.

For example let's assume that in some block scope the user defined a list

```
{
    struct Node *head = NULL;
    struct Node **head_ref = NULL;

    //... Then the list is filled with data
    //... and now the user decided to free the list
    //... but forgot to reassign the pointer head_ref
    //... like head_ref = &head;

    freeList( head_ref );
}
```

In this case the program will have numerous memory leaks. Your function does not help the user to discover that because it will do its work silently. That is your function with such a check makes programs that use your function error prone.

For example the Standard function `free` does not check whether the passed to it pointer is a valid pointer. Or all C standard string function do not check whether a pointer to a string passed to a string function is a null pointer. There is written in the C Standard (7.1.4 Use of library functions)

> 1 Each of the following statements applies unless explicitly stated
> otherwise in the detailed descriptions that follow: **If ... a null
> pointer the behavior is undefined**.

Comment: I don't see this is a good answer by itself. There are valid reasons to want your function to happily ignore a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: @ThomasJager If you think such a way then write a proposal to the C Standard committee that all standard C string functions  shall check that a passed pointer is equal to NULL.

Comment: They do, if you use the newer bounds-checked versions like `strcpy_s`. Changing them now would be incredibly risky, since simple code that is safe in a newer version of C would be completely unsafe in an older (but still modern) one.

Comment: @ThomasJager You are mistaken. In the description of the function there is written "Neither s1 nor s2 shall be a null pointer"

Comment: @ThomasJager It is just a bad style of programming when basic functions make numerous checks. They should be as simple as possible.

Comment: Those are listed as runtime-constraints, as opposed to causing undefined behaviour. `strcpy_s` may have been a bad example because its failure can generally not be ignored in a program's logic.

Comment: @ThomasJager The word "shall" means that if the condition is not satisfied then the function has undefined behavior. You need to learn the C Standard.

Comment: On your note on `free`, the standard states "If ptr is a null pointer, no action occurs." Is there something I've missed from the standard?

Comment: @ThomasJager You have missed because I wrote about "invalid"[pointer that is for example a pointer that does not point to a dynamically allocated memory or a pointer that points to already freed memory. A null pointer is a valid pointer in the context of the function free. There is explicitly written in the C Standard " If ptr is a null pointer, no action occurs". That is it is well-defined behavior.

Comment: I would have to say that I disagree with those who have downvoted this answer. Remember, passing a NULL pointer to the OP's routine is not something that can happen in normal running - it represents a programming error on the part of the programmer who calls this routine. So this answer's proposal of an `assert()` to detect it is a perfectly fine example of "Design by Contract".